# Aplicacion para mandar mensajes de texto a celulares

Tags: java, email

Me gustaria saber como puedo desarrollar una aplicacion en java que me permita enviar mensajes de texto a varios celulares.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que debes definir es deseas tener tu mismo el [gateway](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerta_de_enlace) o contratas los servicios de un tercero y lo consumes a traves de un api.

Para la primera opción te recomiendo dar una mirada a los diferentes proyectos en [github](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=sms%20gateway&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93), Entre ellos te menciono:

- http://smssync.ushahidi.com/, facil de usar, buena documentacion
- [https://github.com/jookies/jasmin/](https://github.com/jookies/jasmin), de grado empresarial, buena documentacion, un monton de caracteristicas que la hacen unica
- https://github.com/haxpax/gosms, buena, rapida y facil de usar, puedes probarla desde tu equipo sin mucho inconveniente

> Para todas las anteriores tienes que hacer un ver si existe un cliente que consuma sus respectivas api

la segunda opción es usar servicios pagos, muchos ya tienen clientes implementados para una multitud de lenguajes incluido JAVA, entre ellas:

- https://www.bulksms.com/products/sms-api.htm
- https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us
- https://www.nexmo.com/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/78926)

Comment: mejorada, gracias por la correción

Comment: Hola JWCastillo, te sugiero revisar [answer] , en realidad la pregunta es demasiado amplia, ¿enviar mensajes de texto a varios celulares? debes incluir las partes reelevantes de los enlaces como indica Marcos.